# Shutdown Red5 failed on every attempt

Tags: java, vps

I'm at my wits end. I have asked everywhere. I've uninstalled - reinstalled countless times in countless different ways and STILL Red5 fails to shutdown.

Can someone please give me a clue?

Not even any answers at Google group Red5 so far having to re-install my entire system on VPS which I really don't want to have to do, there must be someone who has run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, as usual it was something very simple and logical.

The INIT script which is the script that goes in /etc/init.d/ to initialise startup and shutdown. Not all init scripts are the same!

So I am going to share how I got my RED5 service to work altogether.

This is for CentOs 6.4 32bit on linux VPS and actually I ended up reinstalling my system trying to figure my mistake but there was nothing wrong with my system set up.

So first the java rpm so you don't need apache ant. Thanks to @slm

> $ wget --no-check-certificate                              \

```
--no-cookies                                           \

--header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" \
"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jdk-7-linux-i586.rpm"
```

Then `rpm -ivh jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm`

Now install latest RED5 version which is currently RC2 (release candidate 2 above RC1)

> 

```
 cd /usr/local/

 wget http://red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0/red5-1.0.0-RC2.tar.gz

 tar -xzvf red5-1.0.0.tar.gz

 rm red5-1.0.0.tar.gz

 mv red5-1.0.0 red5
```

Now the all important INIT script.

`vi /etc/init.d/red5`

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>   # For RedHat and cousins:
>   # chkconfig: 2345 85 85
>   # description: Red5 flash streaming server
>   # processname: red5
> ```

```
  PROG=red5
  RED5_HOME=/usr/local/red5
  DAEMON=$RED5_HOME/$PROG.sh
  PIDFILE=/var/run/$PROG.pid

  # Source function library
  . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

  [ -r /etc/sysconfig/red5 ] && . /etc/sysconfig/red5

  RETVAL=0

  case "$1" in
  start)
  echo -n $"Starting $PROG: "
  cd $RED5_HOME
  $DAEMON >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
  RETVAL=$?
  if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
  echo $! > $PIDFILE
  touch /var/lock/subsys/$PROG

  fi
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && success $"$PROG startup" || failure $"$PROG startup"
  echo
  ;;
  stop)
  echo -n $"Shutting down $PROG: "
  killproc -p $PIDFILE
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$PROG
  ;;
  restart)
  $0 stop
  $0 start
  ;;
  status)
  status $PROG -p $PIDFILE
  RETVAL=$?
  ;;
  *)
  echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
  RETVAL=1
  esac

  exit $RETVAL
```

Activate init script:

> ```
> chmod 755 /etc/init.d/red5
>   chkconfig red5 --add
>   chkconfig red5 on
> ```

Update settings which are located at:

> ```
> /usr/local/red5/conf/* (actually not sure about this part!)
> ```

Run it:

> ```
> /etc/init.d/red5 start
> ```

I'm sure any number of init scripts work but sometimes you need to put the directory of your JDK files in the script and I just find the above script easier. But in case you want to know, they are located in `/usr/lib/jvm`